# Vectorize Bloom Filter operations for numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, bloom-filter

How can I make use of `numpy`'s vector operations for a Bloom Filter implementation? I started from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bloom-filters-introduction-and-python-implementation/ and modified for naive `ndarray` support.

Remark: I'm not bound to `mmh3` - this was just the only library that allowed me to make use of seeded hashing for generating multiple hash functions.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import mmh3
from bitarray import bitarray

class BloomFilter(object):
    def __init__(self, items_count: int = 100_000, fp_prob : float = 0.01):
        self.fp_prob = fp_prob
        self.size = self.get_size(items_count, fp_prob)
        self.hash_count = self.get_hash_count(self.size, items_count)
        self.bit_array = bitarray(self.size)
        self.bit_array.setall(0)

    def add(self, item):
        if type(item) is np.ndarray:
            for i in item.reshape(-1):
                self.add(i)
        else:
            digest = self.digest(item)
            for pos in digest:
                self.bit_array[pos] = True
    
    def digest(self, item):
        return [mmh3.hash(item, seed=i) % self.size for i in range(self.hash_count)]

    def contains(self, item):
        if type(item) is np.ndarray:
            return np.array(
                [self.contains(i) for i in item.reshape(-1)], 
                dtype=np.bool8
            ).reshape(item.shape)
        else:
            return all(self.bit_array[pos] for pos in self.digest(item))

    @classmethod
    def get_size(self, n, p):
        return int(-(n * math.log(p))/(math.log(2)**2))

    @classmethod
    def get_hash_count(self, m, n):
        return int((m/n) * math.log(2))


items = np.random.randint(size=1_000_000, low=0, high=2**60, dtype=np.int64)
set_of_items = BloomFilter(items.size, 0.001)
set_of_items.add(items)

items2 = np.random.randint(size=100_000, low=0, high=2**60, dtype=np.int64)
existing = set_of_items.contains(items2)
new_items = items2[~existing]

print(f"#{len(new_items)}")
```